# OnPointerEnter being blocked by canvas group

Tags: unity-game-engine

I set up an inventory system, now i am working on setting up the ability to open and close it. I figured i could use a canvas group to set the alpha to 0 and then disable the relevant lines of code in the inventory scripts. Im not at that point yet, because the canvas group has stopped OnPointerEnter from working. [image: pointer enter code] Here is the code for the pointer enter.

[image: first heirarchy setup]
it does not work when the heirarchy is like this.

[image: second heirarchy setup]
but it does work when the heirarchy is set up this way, so im pretty sure the issue is the canvas group is blocking the inventoryGrid OnPointerEnter from working.

So, why does the canvas group block the pointerEnter, and is there a way around it? Or will i have to just have a better way of hiding the inventory screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Interactable and BlockRaycasts properties of your CanvasGroup. You can find more info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-CanvasGroup.html).

Comment: I had to turn on "block raycasts" I thought i tried that at one point but i guess i didnt.